# Embed Excel in a website to edit a locally stored document

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, office-web-components

Is it possible to embed google excel in my website to edit document stored locally?

My manager asked me if it is possible to integrate the Microsoft office webapp in my own website.

Clients have excel files stored on our website, we want to know if it is possible for them to open the file with a web excel page, edit the file and save the modifications. For now, they use SharePoint so it is easy for them but we intend to use an other platform.

Our client can have all the license we need.

I searched but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: You can setup a ftp server and keep the files over there and create a user account for the ftp server and give it to your client. where they can edit the file and will also be available on web.

Answer (score 0):

I know you should be able to do this with ASP and the .Net Framework. SharePoint uses ASP pages, so you may try to do something simpler.

If you go over the Internet you'll see several solutions because people do this too.

e.g. a thing you can do is to use [Open XML API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) to do this, and it is like reading / modifying a flat file on the server. A restriction is it has to be .xlsx / 2007 format onward.